# Inserting Chart on Google Scripts causes "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id..." Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following code to insert a chart into a google sheet:

```
var range1 = copySheet.getRange(3, 1, 5);
var range2 = copySheet.getRange(3, 5, 5); //copySheet is from a separate spreadsheet

var chart = sheet.newChart().asLineChart()
   .addRange(range1) 
   .addRange(range2) //range 1 and 2 are taken from another spreadsheet
   .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
   .setPosition(graphPositionDictionary[runOrderList[order]],
         sheet.getRange(graphPositionDictionary[runOrderList[order]], 1).getValue(), 0, 0)
   .setTitle("Title")
   .setNumHeaders(1)
   .setOption('hAxis', hAxisOptions)
   .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
   .setOption("vAxis.viewWindow.max", 5000)
   .build();

   sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

However, the script always fails at the last line, where the chart is inserted, with the error message "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id...". The active spreadsheet is mostly empty, so the 5,000,000 row limit is not met (which can apparently also cause this error to occur).

Is it possible that the reason for this error is that the ranges copied from are from a separate spreadsheet? And if so, is there a workaround to this?

I know that there is an alternative way to create a line chart through scripts using something like:

```
var chart = Charts.newLineChart()
.setTitle("Title")
.setDataTable(recipeData);
.build();
```

However, to my knowledge, the .setPosition function does not work here, as well as the .insertChart() function. As an alternate question, is there a way to place the graph created through "UiApp.createApplication()" to a specified cell in the active spreadsheet, similar to the .setPosition function?

Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: which line of the code causing the error?  can you share the code?

Comment: "sheet.insertChart(chart);" is the line of code causing the error, which is part of the first code block in the post. Let me know if I need to share previous sections to help clarify

Comment: @km123 can you check your execution logs and get the full exception details? - AFAIK, the threshold applies for *all* the worksheet.

Comment: "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id...". if you are getting this error. It has great chance about the authorization and the access right issue.   Can you just call the sheet? to see if you getting any errors.   SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)